# Exception: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to parse the following page: https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCJWCJCWOxBYSi5DhCieLOLQ to grab the following all the yt:video id elements, e.g. and save them to an array/list i.e:

```
<yt:videoId>_V0vqy046YM</yt:videoId>

...

<yt:videoId>_V1vqy046YM</yt:videoId>

...

<yt:videoId>_V2vqy046YM</yt:videoId>
```

However I keep getting the following error message, how do I fix it?

`Exception: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

This is my code so far:

```
try:
    recent_video_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=' + channel_id
    print('Querying:', recent_video_url)
    recent_video_response = requests.get(recent_video_url)
    recent_video_response_data = recent_video_response.content
    root = tree.fromstring(recent_video_response_data)
    for child in root.findall('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry'):
        print(child.find('yt:videoId').text)
except Exception as e:
    raise Exception(e)
```

Comment: Looks like you found a child with no `yt:videoId`. Do some troubleshooting to find out which one, and decide how you want to deal with similar cases.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. All the childs have yt:videoId, did a check at https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCJWCJCWOxBYSi5DhCieLOLQ

Comment: Well, your code thinks there is. Add a check to find when `child.find('yt:video')` is `None`, and print out the contents of the `child`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Et


try:
    channel_id = 'UCJWCJCWOxBYSi5DhCieLOLQ'
    recent_video_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=' + channel_id

    print('Querying:', recent_video_url)
    recent_video_response = requests.get(recent_video_url)

    tree = Et.ElementTree(Et.fromstring(recent_video_response.content))
    namespaces = {'yt': 'http://www.youtube.com/xml/schemas/2015'}

    recent_video_response_data = [element.text for element in tree.findall('.//yt:videoId', namespaces=namespaces)]
    print(recent_video_response_data)
except Exception as e:
    raise Exception(e)
```